# Can Shield UI Chart Tooltip be different for multiple Charts on the same Page?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, tooltip, shieldui

I have read through all the Documentation on the Shield UI website, but could only find a single statement related to the Chart Tooltip:

```
tooltipSettings: {
customHeaderText: "Local point Value: ",
customPointText: function (point, chart) {
                return shield.format(
                    '<span><b>{value}</b></span>',
                    {
                        value: point.y
                    }
                );
            }
},
```

If this is changed for any Chart, the Tooltips for all Charts on the Page changes.

I have a radio button to switch between Number and Percentage and so need the Tooltip to include a '%' just for that Chart.

Does anyone have a way to change the Tooltip for a Single Chart without affecting the others?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this was a bug in the chart component and they are fixed it. I tested with the latest version of the scripts from the [shieldui chart](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/bar-chart/basic-usage) [demos’ web site](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/area-chart/basic-usage) and everything works as expected.

Can you try using following script reference and let me know if the issue still persists:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>
```

I use following example:

```
<div id="chart1" ></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="chart2"></div>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#chart2").shieldChart({
    theme: "light",
    exportOptions: {
        image: false,
        print: false
    },

    seriesSettings: {
        bar: {
            stackMode: "normal"
        }
    },
    axisX: {
        categoricalValues: [
            "1952", "1956", "1960", "1964", "1968", "1972", "1976",
            "1984", "1988", "1992", "1996", "2000", "2004", "2008", "2012"
        ]
    },
    primaryHeader: {
        text: "Olympic Medals won by USA"
    },
    dataSeries: [{
        seriesType: "bar",
        collectionAlias: "Gold Medals",
        data: [40, 32, 34, 36, 45, 33, 34, 83, 36, 37, 44, 37, 35, 36, 46],
        stackIndex: 1
    }, {
        seriesType: "bar",
        collectionAlias: "Silver Medals",
        data: [19, 25, 21, 26, 28, 31, 35, 60, 31, 34, 32, 24, 40, 38, 29],
        stackIndex: 1
    }, {
        seriesType: "bar",
        collectionAlias: "Silver Medals1",
        data: [19, 25, 21, 26, 28, 31, 35, 60, 31, 34, 32, 24, 40, 38, 29],
        stackIndex: 2
    },
    {
        seriesType: "bar",
        collectionAlias: "Bronze Medals",
        data: [17, 17, 16, 28, 34, 30, 25, 30, 27, 37, 25, 33, 26, 36, 29],
        stackIndex: 2
    }]
});

$("#chart1").shieldChart({
    theme: "light",
    tooltipSettings: {
        customHeaderText: "Local point Value: ",
        customPointText: function (point, chart) {
            return shield.format(
                '<span><b>{value}</b></span>',
                {
                    value: point.y
                }
            );
        }
    },
    axisX: {
        categoricalValues: [
            "1952", "1956", "1960", "1964", "1968", "1972", "1976",
            "1984", "1988", "1992", "1996", "2000", "2004", "2008", "2012"
        ]
    },
    primaryHeader: {
        text: "Olympic Medals won by USA"
    },
    dataSeries: [{
        seriesType: "bar",
        collectionAlias: "Gold Medals",
        data: [40, 32, 34, 36, 45, 33, 34, 83, 36, 37, 44, 37, 35, 36, 46],
    }]
});});
```

Comment: The issue still persists

Comment: I have downloaded Non-Commercial version 1.7.8 and linked it, but I still see the issue

Comment: Can you post your code? Did you tried the code which I post?